# Cannot find module when i create my own module for library

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

Sorry to ask for a question like that but it's very weird and i cannot find where the issue come from.

I just want to create a module for a library i have installed (scroll-to) and when i compile my code to JS and i get my mouse over the import its say "Could not find a declaration file for module 'scroll-to'." and some others lines..

Here my "scroll-to.d.ts"

```
declare module "scroll-to" {
const scrollTo: (x: number, y: number, options: {
    ease?: string,
    duration?: number
}) => void

export default scrollTo
```

}

"app.ts"

```
import scrollTo from 'scroll-to' 

scrollTo(500, 1200, {
ease: 'out-bounce',
duration: 1500
});
```

"app.js" in /dist

```
import scrollTo from 'scroll-to';
scrollTo(500, 1200, {
ease: 'out-bounce',
duration: 1500
```

});

"tsconfig.json"

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ES2021",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    
},
"files": [
    "src/app.ts"
],
"include": [
    "src/types/**/*"
]
```

}

"package.json"

```
{
  "name": "ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "scroll-to": "^0.0.2"
  }
}
```

Also my script is imported with a type="module" in the html.
I really don't know what wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## Implementing your custom package locally

If you're defining your `scroll-to.d.ts` file within your project workspace, keep in mind that by default Typescript is going to look for types under `node_modules/**/@types` and `node_modules/@types` only. Ergo that `d.ts` file will not necessarily be seen by your Typescript configuration by default.

You can utilize the [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) config option to tell it to look for your types file (keep in mind though it clobbers the default behavior).

Try adding the following to your `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"]
  }
}
```

And see if that solves the issue.

---

## Installing your custom package

If you're installing your custom package and not having types resolved, then that likely means you didn't package your types with your package.

Ensure that the [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package) property in your custom package's `package.json` is set, and that you're including your `.d.ts` files in your [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#files) property.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunaly is not working. I have also added my package.json to my post, and this one throw me a message "Problems loading reference 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults': Unable to load schema from..."

Comment: Ok so a quick clarification for my understanding. Your package.json suggests you're installing the package rather than locally implementing it. Is that correct? If so then you need to make sure you're including your types in the package itself when you publish it.

Comment: Yes, but after a restart my package.json don't show me the message again

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've added a second set of instructions for resolving types when you're installing the package rather than locally implementing it.

Comment: I changed and I edited the package.json from my post, you can check. But it's not working, I got this error from the console "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "scroll-to". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."
This happen when I write type="module" in the HTML script.
Else i got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: If you are installing your package into node_modules as a dependency then you need to go through the second set of instructions I provided for bundling your types with your package. 

The module import is a separate issue

Comment: Thank for your help, but absolutly nothing is working. I posted my folder on Github if someone want to take 2 minutes to check : https://github.com/Nico7522/test-ts

Comment: Hi @Ncls7523, sorry for the late response, life got busy. I cloned your repo and didn't have any issues resolving the types...